# I can´t see my image when I use "Image texture"

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

First I click on my object, then I select the materials tab and I create a new material. Then I add a "image texture" in "node editor" and charge the png image, but I can't see it as a final result when I select "rendered" or "material" viewport.

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Did you unwrap the mesh?

Comment: Also try adding texture coordinates to the image texture vector node input.

Comment: And double check the faces of your mesh are assigned to the correct  material